# Tool Tip jQuery to appear outside slide element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a jQuery conundrum that I'm not sure can be resolved. Inside a content slider I have absolutely positioned divs creating a tool-tip style pop-up on hover. Because the containing content slider overflow must be set to hidden, the tool-tip pop-up gets cut off where it overflows. I would like the pop-up to display in full when overlapping the slider it is contained within. If anyone has a workaround for this I'd be very appreciative!

Here's [a link](http://www.stimulatingminds.co.uk/test/slidepopup/index.html) to my working file from which you can see the problem and the code.

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: will u please refer the plugin  link , which you r using for tooltip

Comment: Hi, here's a link to a tutorial for the pop-up that I've adapted: http://www.mastermind-solutions.com/jquery/create-a-jquery-popup-bubble-effect/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Your animation inside 'slidesContainer' relies on overflow:hidden so the large image doesn't stick out of the div and the only way for you to get the balloons pop out is to remove that overflow:hidden and make it visible

I don't think you can have the two at the same time

Comment: Hi XGreen, I feared that might be the case but hoped there might be some kind of work-around out there. Possibly not though.

Comment: I struggled with this about a month ago on google maps...as it has the same issue...and didn't find a way to get the map balloons to stick out

Answer (score 0):

Right, so I don't think there was a straight forward solution so what I did was change the script to refer to div IDs instead of referring to the 'next' div. I moved the pop-up div's outside the slide element and absolutely positioned them relative to the page rather than the link. It's more long winded but works fine! Just means you need to refer individually to each pop-up div in the script. Thanks for you help anyway!